# selection check-box is not showing properly in UI-Grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using UI-grid in which check-box is not showing properly. I have verified all files but not get any issue in my code.

Please suggest where i am wrong?

Comment: can you show your code or fiddle ?

Comment: Show the image of what you see. Share the code with the templates you are using?